# Streaming Audio file in MVC with Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5-audio, audio-streaming, video.js

I would want to stream an audio file without entirely downloading the file.

For now I have used .Net MVC app. It doesn't matter as the HTML remains the same.

```
<audio controls ref="audioElement1">
    <source src="@Url.Action("GetNextChunk", "Home")" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

If this was HTML it would look more like

```
<audio
      ref="audioElement1"
      src="http://localhost:7074/home/getNextChunk/"      
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    ></audio>
```

Here is my Web API

```
[HttpGet, Route("getNextChunk1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetNextChunk()
        {
            string fileName = "someaudio.mp3";
            string filePath = $@"c:\\AudioDummy\\{fileName}";

            if (filePath != null)
            {
                long fileSize = (new FileInfo(filePath)).Length;
                long startByte = 0;
                long endByte = fileSize - 1;
                HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

                //if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Range"))
                //{
                //    // Get the actual byte range from the range header string and set the starting byte.
                //    string[] range = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Range").ToString().Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
                //    startByte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
                //    if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "")
                //        endByte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);

                //    // If the start byte is not equal to zero, that means the user is requesting partial content.
                //    if (startByte != 0 || endByte != fileSize - 1 || (range.Length > 2 && range[2] == ""))
                //    {
                //        statusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent; // Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.
                //    }
                //}

                long contentSize = endByte - startByte + 1;

                // Prepare the response message
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ReadRangeFromFile(filePath, startByte, contentSize))
                };

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mpeg");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentSize;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(startByte, endByte, fileSize);

                return response;
            }

            // If the filename parameter is missing, return BadRequest
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

For now I have commented the range check. This is to support partial play and not waiting for entire video to be sent back.

I can see the response in Web API but the audio doesn't play. The error is not that much useful, its on checking the file type.

Anything I am missing here?

Any leads are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I see what the problem is, it is serialized in .net core and majority of answers were on .net 4.8.

I tried FileStream and it worked, but that doesn't help giving range headers.